# How to change state in a component on click of a button from another Component?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I want that the user should be able to see the logout link in header once he is logged in.

The logout link is in Header.jsx:

```
export default function Header() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
    }
    else {
      setLoggedIn(false);
    }
  },[setLoggedIn]);

  
  function logout() {
    setLoggedIn(false);
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.href = '/';
}
    return (
        <div>
            <header>
              <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark text-light">
                  <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">                    
                    <li className="nav-item pull-right">
                      <a className="nav-link text-white" style={{display:loggedIn?'block':'none'}} href="/login" onClick={()=>{logout()}}>Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    
                  </ul>
                
              </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The Login component has a form which on submitting, logs the user in.
Now If the user clicks on Log in, the state of loggedIn used in the above Header component should change to true so that Logout link can be displayed on Header.
The Log in Component is:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from '../authenticate/Authenticate';

export default function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();

    const loginHandler = (e) => {
    //Here I want to change the state of loggedIn so that Logout link can be dislayed on Header.
      e.preventDefault();
        const user = {username, password};
        auth.authenticateFunc(callApi, user);
    }

    const callApi = (user)=>{
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/auth/v1`,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(user),      
    }).then((res)=>{
        if(res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        }
    }).then(data=>{
      if(data) {
        localStorage.setItem('token',data.token);
        history.push('/');
      }
      else {
        setErrorMsg('Please enter correct credentials');
        return null;
      }
    })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="wrapper">
              <div id="formContent">
                
                {/* <!-- Login Form --> */}
                <form>
                  <div><span>{errorMsg}</span></div>
                  <input type="text" data-testid="uname" id="username" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} placeholder="username"/>
                  
                  <input type="password" data-testid="pass" id="password" value={password} onChange={(e)=>{setPassword(e.target.value)}} placeholder="password"/>
                  
                  <input type="submit" data-testid="loginBtn" onClick={(e)=>loginHandler(e)} value="Log In"/>
                  
                  <a href="/register">New User? Register here</a>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    )
}
```

I have seen various answers for questions like this but I'm unable to understand how to do this.

Comment: You could do that with firing `CustomEvent` on document and listening it to update the state.

Comment: Thanks. I did that with the help from https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-communicate-between-independent-components-in-reactjs